# Error only in Azure App Service: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, azure, nullreferenceexception, azureservicebus

I have a continuously running job (service) that I'm trying to deploy to Azure as an App Service.  It was created in Visual Studio as a typical Console App, and then it uses TopShelf to run as a service.

Currently, we are deploying this service to a windows box hosted in Rack Space.  But we are moving away form that model towards Azure.  Both in debug on my local machine, and on the Rack Space windows server, it runs perfectly.  But when I deploy to Azure, I get the Object Reference error.

The purpose of this service in incredibly simple: Query an Azure Service Bus for messages, if there are any, put them in a list, and then hand the list off to another class that processes them.  That's it.  The actual pining of the service bus ins't done within this project or class.  For that it depends on QueueAccess, which is a separate class.

```
public class MessageQueueQuery : IMessageQueueQuery
{
    ...
    private QueueAccess queueAccess;  // QueueAccess is a reference to another project.

    public void Start()
    {
        ...
        queueAccess = new QueueAccess();
        ...

        // Go get the messages
        try
        {
            messageList = queueAccess.GetMessageCollection();  // <-- ERROR IS HERE
        }
            catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.ErrorFormat("Error in retreiving a list of messages from queue.", ex);
        }
```

Again, this works in every instance OTHER than when deployed to Azure as an App Service. Identical code across the board. I'm thinking that maybe I'm doing the deploy wrong?  And for some reason the .dll for QueueAccess isn't being sent up along with the deployment?  Although when I log in via FTP I can see it sitting there along with the rest of the files.

Here's the complete log entry:

```
2016-05-20T20:56:08  PID[10568] Information    at XXXXXX.Queue.Core.MessageQueueQuery.ProcessMessages() in C:\XXXXXXGit\XXXXXX\Main\XXXXXX.Queue.Core\MessageQueueQuery.cs:line 108

2016-05-20T20:56:08  PID[10568] Information 2016-05-20 20:56:08,156 [5] ERROR XXXXXX.Queue.WindowsService.Bootstrapper [(null)] - Error in retrieving a list of messages from queue.
```

I'm not sure why it's not working.

Comment: Are you using Topshelf for Azure  https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf.Azure ?

Comment: I did not know about that.  I'll check it out.

Comment: The answer is, "No".  But... would it matter?  The app IS running as a service.  If not, it would not have logged that error.  Would an Azure specific version of TopShelf (or lack there of) cause third party .dll's to work or fail?

Comment: To be clear, the error doesn't appear to be originating in your MessageQueueQuery class... it's looks like its only being surfaced there. Can you post the full stack trace of the exception? That should give a better indication of the underlying issue.

Comment: @JoshL, I've given all I have in the OP.  That's all that shows up in the logs.  (I'm still trying to figure out how logging works with App Services to get access to full stack traces.)

Comment: Have you turned on Application Insights? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-get-started/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a TopShelf user BUT:

In Rackspace, I guess your app runs in a VM (IaaS).
In App Service, your app runs in PaaS, not IaaS.

1. You can try to deploy your app to an Azure VM instead.
2. Or check TopShelf compatibility with Azure PaaS. They seem to provide a solution for Worker roles (= part of Azure PaaS v1) https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf.Azure
3. You can also check native Azure PaaS v2 solutions to run web jobs  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/

Comment: Ok, so swapping out TopShelf for TopShelf.Azure has for sure gotten things moving.  It solved this problem, plus another I was seeing as well with Log4net that I hadn't yet gotten around to tackling.  Thank you!!